# HTML5 Drag and Drop of Files not working in Opera

Tags: javascript, html, opera

The code excerpted below works in IE/FF/Chrome/Safari/etc, but not in Opera.
Opera gives a "Do you want to upload your files to www.webserver.edu?" dialog, but neither answering Yes or No seems to let the "drop" event fire.  No errors are logged in the error console.  Also, dragging other content (strings from the page) works as expected.

```
<input type="file" id="fileselect" name="fileselect" multiple="multiple">
<div id="filedrag">or drag files here</div>
...
$(document).ready(function() {
        function DragDropEvent(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                e.preventDefault();
                e.target.className = ((e.type == "dragover") ||
                                      (e.type == "dragenter")) ? "hover" : "";
                if (e.type == "drop") {
                        var files = (e.dataTransfer && e.dataTransfer.files);
                        if (files && files.length > 0) UploadFile(files);
                }
        }
        function Init() {
                var filedrag = document.getElementById("filedrag");
                filedrag.addEventListener("dragenter", DragDropEvent, false);
                filedrag.addEventListener("dragover", DragDropEvent, false);
                filedrag.addEventListener("dragleave", DragDropEvent, false);
                filedrag.addEventListener("drop", DragDropEvent, false);
        }
        if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
                Init();
        }
}
```

Comment: Which version of Opera? Which operating system?

Comment: Opera 12.16 under OS X

Comment: The current version of Opera for OS X is 34… you might want to upgrade. 12.16 is so old it still has Opera's abandoned in-house rendering engine.

Comment: That's interesting, it does appear to work correctly on Opera 34.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: When I check for updates, it tells me "You are using the latest version of Opera".

Comment: They might have locked it down to stop people being automatically switched over to the new rendering engine. A manual install will resolve that.

Comment: A manual install did the trick and Opera 34 is working correctly under OS X too.   Geez, trusting Opera's stupid updater cost me a stupid amount of hair-pulling!   Thanks @Quentin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is actually fine as long as you have a reasonably new version of Opera.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine even in Opera 12.16 (under Linux) with one exception I will describe below.

- `OK` If you select one file only **it works** as expected.
- `KO` If you select **multiple files at once only the first one is seen**, the event doesn't capture the other files (actually it captures the others but they are seen as strings of *text/uri-list* type instead of as *files*). I assume this is a bug in older version of Opera (like 12.16) because I see the same behaviour in a demo page written by Opera Developers (https://dev.opera.com/articles/drag-and-drop/demo.html)

However, the code will work 100% (single/multiple files at once) if you are using a newer version Opera.